# Como aplicar quebra de linha após uma imagem?

Tags: html, css, material-ui

Possuo uma `img` e um `Button`, ambos estão dentro de um `Grid` da biblioteca **material react-ui**.
Meu objetivo é centralizar horizontal e vertical ambos a imagem e o botão no espaço disponível `xs={4}`, porém, preciso de uma quebra de linha após a imagem.

O que eu tentei:

```
<Grid container justify="center" alignItems="center" item xs={4}>
  <img style={{maxWidth: '50px', minWidth: '50px'}} src={imageSource} />
  <br />
  <Button
    color="primary"
  >
      Procurar
  </Button>
</Grid>
```

Porém após a imagem, não está ocorrendo a quebra de linha.

Também tentei:

```
<br clear="all" />
```

Fiz uma reprodução no [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-cerf-vwvm6?file=/src/App.js) caso alguém tenha interesse em tentar me ajudar

Comment: Já pensou em mudar a direção do grid? Ou não se aplica para o que você está produzindo...

Comment: @DanielMendes eu realmente optei por outra alternativa, com display block e text-align, talvez não a melhor solução, mas atendeu ao esperado. Vou adicionar uma resposta em breve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ola,

Com o componente de Grade do Material-UI é possivel ir aninhando os itens dessa forma.

```
<Grid container item xs={4}>
  <Grid container item xs={12} alignItems="center" justify="center">
    <img
      alt="Outro Gato"
      style={{ maxWidth: "50px", minWidth: "50px" }}
      src="http:\\suaurldeimagem"
    />
  </Grid>
  <Grid container item xs={12} alignItems="center" justify="center">
    <Button color="primary">Procurar</Button>
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Aqui a reprodução no [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-stonebraker-pf1bn)

Como a documentação da [Grade](https://material-ui.com/pt/components/grid/) nos diz, lembre-se que a Grade sempre se baseia em um leiaute responsivo de 12 colunas, as propriedades [xs, sm, md, lg, xl] ajudam a posicionar os itens dentro do contêiner.